# Catalina Dynamic Wallpaper doesn't change with the time of the day

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, wallpaper

Both Apple stock dynamic wallpapers aren't changing accordingly to the time of the day. For example Catalina Dynamic wallpaper is stuck during the day in one picture and it doesn't change and transition. Night time Catalina Dynamic wallpaper isn't completely dark, but looks like sunset one. And Auto Appearance doesn't work either, sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't.
What can I do, as I tried resetting, doing PRAM, changing wallpapers, trying 3rd party apps like Night Owl, sacrificing virgins to the volcano, idk. Help!

Comment: I have a similar problem: when I create a new desktop, its wallpaper is the appropriate one from the time of day, but existing desktops never get their wallpaper updated during the time of day. It just never worked for me (not in Mojave nor in Catalina)

Comment: They are supposed to work based on the sun angle (over the horizon) and azimuth. Maybe there's something wrong with the geographical position that your system sees. I assume that when behind the polar circle, during the polar day you won't see the dark version of the photo at all.

Answer (score 0):

Same for me... I tried to play with the manual time setting. Set different times and checked if the wallpaper changed accordingly. There seems to be NO night wallpaper for me... Only when you set the standard non-dynamic one. After playing around with the time settings, my dynamic-wallpaper is now totally confused. It's 01:30AM and it looks like sunset/sunrise in the wallpaper...

Comment: This is not an answer. Would be better as a comment on the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to still be buggy as of macOS 12.4 Monterey (July 2022). When trying to select a custom dynamic wallpaper, the System Preferences interface seems to run into some issues.

[image: Buggy System Preferences UI with custom dynamic wallpaper selected]

For best results on this, however, there is a workaround that seems to work.

1. In System Preferences, select a built-in Apple Dynamic Wallpaper
2. In Finder, navigate to your custom dynamic wallpaper file
3. Right click the file
4. Hover "Services"
5. Select "Set Desktop Picture"

[image]

The wallpaper will change to your custom wallpaper and it should change as the time progresses throughout the day.

Thanks to `allenliao` for posting this workaround on [Apple Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253340244).